# Statistic based on year and month

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a system which uses Cloud Firestore from firebase. The website has staff users who can write predictions regarding the stock market. The outcome of the prediction is then being added to the users statistic document which contains information such as total profit, total money spent, ROI etc, this is done using batch. I would like to show the users statistics based on:

- Yearly
- Monthly
- All time

The users statistic document currently look like this:

```
{
   ROI: 50,
   totalProfit: 1000,
   totalSpent: 1000,
   ...
}
```

I would like to show the users monthly and yearly statistics as well, what i have thought about doing so far is this:

```
     {
      "stats": {
        "2020": {
          "ROI": 50,
          "totalProfit": 1000,
          "totalSpent": 1000,
          "monthly": {
            "january": {
              "ROI": 50,
              "totalProfit": 1000,
              "totalSpent": 1000
            },
            "february": {
              "ROI": 50,
              "totalProfit": 1000,
              "totalSpent": 1000
            }
          }
        },
        "2019": {
          "ROI": 50,
          "totalProfit": 1000,
          "totalSpent": 1000,
          "monthly": {
            "january": {
              "ROI": 50,
              "totalProfit": 1000,
              "totalSpent": 1000
            },
            "february": {
              "ROI": 50,
              "totalProfit": 1000,
              "totalSpent": 1000
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I would really avoid to make the statistic calculation every time a user is requesting the statistics, since it's accuring basically all the time. The only major issue i'm facing with this method is that, when it's new month or year i have to create the object field "February" since it doesn't exist yet, and cannot seem to find a pretty solution for that.

Is there another option that i'm missing out on, or is this solution OK?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is here: "The only major issue i'm facing with this method is that, when it's new month or year i have to create the object field `February` since it doesn't exist yet". Can you show what you tried for that and where you got stiuck on it?

Comment: actually, i think i have made it work now, but i'm still unsure about the whole structure of the statistics, whether or not it's a good design